# OpenRefine - replacing string value in one column based no the value in another

Tags: data-cleaning, openrefine

I have a large CSV which contains information about how a collection is divided up.  For example one column contains information about the top level category, another about the sub-category and there can be quite a few of these depending on sub-classifications.

In OpenRefine these look like(for example):

```
||field 1        || field 2                           || field 3
||I am a section || I am a section with a subsection  ||  I am a section with a subsection with another subsection
```

In order to be able to correctly split these out into top level and subsections I thought perhaps I could use the `replace` function to remove the value of `field1` from the value of `field 2` and onwards.  This would leave me with

```
||field 1        || field 2           || field 3
||I am a section || with a subsection ||  with another subsection
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the right approach or is there something more elegant?
2. Is it is, how do I use the `replace` function to dynamically do this in the entire CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference another column with the following GREL expression: `cells['field 2'].value`

For example, in your case, you will be replacing the value from `field 2`  by nothing (using `''`), the expression is: `value.replace(cells['field 2'].value,'')`